# archive firebase cloud firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, archive

I am almost reaching the storage limitation of firebase, which is 5GB. There are some old data that I don't need any more, so I want to archive those data to my local storage and delete those from firebase.

Is there a tool from Google or 3rd party that I can use to archive those data? I went to firebase web portal, but I couldn't find any option for me to do this.

I can write a tool using admin sdk as well, but wonder if there is an existing tool that is available to do this.

Thanks

Comment: "storage limitation of firebase, which is 5GB." Just to be clear: this limit is only on the free plan. If you upgrade to a paid plan, you'll have a much (!) higher limit.

Comment: understood. will upgrade once it is ready for production.

Answer (score 0):

There is no functionality built into Firebase to archive certain data. If you want this functionality, you will have to build it yourself using the API/SDK.